# DNX (ASP.NET Core RC1) web application - cannot host in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, dnx

I'm trying to deploy an web application still on ASP.NET RC1 (DNX) to IIS. I went through all the Microsoft documentation, but I'm stuck on an issue. I'm getting this error when the application is starting up:

```
Application startup exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Web' or one of its dependencies. General Exception (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500)
File name: 'Web' ---> Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.RoslynCompilationException: Startup.cs(104,39): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0012: The type 'Func<,>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

What does this mean? I am able to deploy to IIS on my local machine that I did the development on without any issues. However, just the server with IIS does not work.

How do I go about solving this error? The server is on Windows Server 2008 R2, and my local machine is Windows 7, if that helps.

Comment: Do you have DNVM installed on your server and the correct dnx runtime?

Comment: @Tseng I don't believe I do, how can I check for sure? I do have the dnx runtime though.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem using a workaround. It looks like it is an issue with Visual Studio 2015's **Publish** command. It looks like it does not have an option to publish into Nuget packages. This means the publish command outputs the source files. Hence the files still need to be compiled by the server.

I did not find out how to let the server compile the files correctly. However, I was able to resolve it by just compiling the code into Nuget packages before-hand. This can be done by using the dnu commandline tool.

```
dnu publish --out %folder% --no-source --include-symbols --runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1 --configuration Release
```

The important part is the `--no-source` option, which will package into Nuget packages.